# Iterating through set $_POST variables by type?

Tags: php

I have user inputs as follows:

```
<form action="special.php" method="post">
    <input name="first1"> <input name="last1"> <input name="age1">
    <input name="first2"> <input name="last2"> <input name="age2">
    <input name="first3"> <input name="last3"> <input name="age3">
    <input name="first4"> <input name="last4"> <input name="age4">
    <input name="first5"> <input name="last5"> <input name="age5">
    <input name="first6"> <input name="last6"> <input name="age6">
    ...

    N
</form>
```

The amount of user inputs in the form is determined by the user; meaning, the user can add 5,10,20 additional lines to the code above, creating new input elements (following the pattern above) as they fit.

My question is, once the form gets submitted, what is an easy way to iterate and print out all the SET POST variables?

Something like:

```
for($i=0; $i < $numPostVars; $i++){
   if(isset($_POST['first".$i."'])){
       //echo all first names post variables that are set
    }
}

// do the same from last names & age in separate loops
```

Comment: what's wrong with your your example? are you getting an error?

Comment: Seems to me like you should be using arrays. Either `first[1]`, `first[2]` etc or (probably better) `rows[1][first]`, `rows[1][last]`, `rows[1][age]`, `rows[2][first]`... etc. If you name your inputs with this syntax, the data will already be structured in nice, easy to use arrays and you can just `foreach()` over them - like `foreach ($_POST['rows'] as $row) { /* stuff with $row['first'] etc */ }`

Comment: @DaveRandom, this is genious, please answer so I can accept your answer as the solution. Your method works fantastic! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inputs can be treated as arrays with a syntax very similar to that used in PHP:

```
<input name="name[1]" value="value 1">
<input name="name[2]" value="value 2">
```

This would result in a `$_POST['name']` that looks like this:

```
array(
  1 => "value 1",
  2 => "value 2"
);
```

This principle can be expanded to incorporate multi-dimensional and associative arrays. So if you were to name your inputs like this:

```
<input name="rows[1][first]"> <input name="rows[1][last]"> <input name="rows[1][age]">
<input name="rows[2][first]"> <input name="rows[2][last]"> <input name="rows[2][age]">
```

...you would be able to easily iterate over `$_POST['rows']` with a `foreach` construct. The data structure will be very similar to a set of database results.

```
foreach ($_POST['rows'] as $row) {
  // do stuff with $row['first'], $row['last'] and $row['age'] here
}
```

A couple of things to note:

- Unlike PHP, associative array keys in HTML do not require quotes, and using them will produce a result you may not expect. It will *work*, but not in the way you might think. You still need to use quotes in PHP though.
- As far as I am aware, this syntax is not a W3C standard. PHP, however, always handles it as expected.

Answer (score 4):

I think the trick is to name your variables slightly different, and take advantage of PHP's feature which will unpack them as arrays for you. Just use the syntax: `first[1]`. Then in PHP, $_POST['first']['1'] is where you will find it. You can then iterate all your "first" inputs with

```
foreach($_POST['first'] as $first_input) {
  // ... 
}
```

Also keep in mind that browsers [may not send the field](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) if it is empty when the user submits.

Here is what the inputs should look like in HTML:

```
<input name="first[1]"> <input name="last[1]"> <input name="age[1]">
```

As noted by user @DaveRandom, consider also a more hierarchical structure (think "rows" like from your db):

```
<input name="people[1][first]"> <input name="people[1][last]"> <input name="people[1][age]">
```

Comment: You can even simplify to first[] in the input names, it will create the indexes as needed.

Comment: @mjayt See my comment on Explosion Pills answer... that is not safe when you need multiple fields to go together consistently.

Comment: A multi-dimensional associative database-result-style array is what is required here, see my comment on the question.

Comment: @DaveRandom why no answer? That's goot stuff!

Comment: Honestly, it's too late and I'm too tired to construct a well explained answer. If you can put it into words/code I'll be happy to upvote it though :-)

Comment: @DaveRandom if you insist... :-)

Comment: I was persuaded by the OP, but enjoy this tasty +1 in any case :-)

Comment: @DaveRandom great! Right back at ya.